# use return function sinde .attr() jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, prettyphoto

On my website, I have included an input field and a button. The input field is used for entering a youtube video code. Upon clicking on the button, I want my site to create a new href by using "www.youtube.com/watch?v=" and adding to it whatever code was entered inside the input field. Then, the youtube video should open inside a lightbox (using prettyPhoto, which I have already installed and which is working just fine).

This is the code I have so far:

```html
<div>
    <br>
    <input type="text" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Video Code" id="code_input">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
        <a href="#" id="youtube" rel="prettyPhoto">
            <button type="button" id="button" onclick="MyFunction">Jetzt anschauen!</button>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function MyFunction () {
                    var baselink="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
                    var youtube_code=document.getElementById("code_input").value;
                    var new_link=baselink.concat(youtube_code);
                }
                $('#youtube').attr("href", function() {
                    return new_link;
                });
            </script>
        </a>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I enter a youtube video code and click on the button, the lightbox opens but returns the following:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GXEc.png)

Could anyone kindly have a look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong? Or kindly explain to me how I can dynamically create a new href based on the input field data and how to feed that into the  tag.

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Found that the following code solves the problem:

```html
<div>
 <br>
    <input type="text" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Video Code" id="code_input">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">             </script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $("button").click(function(){
         var ycode = document.getElementById("code_input").value;
         $('#youtube').attr("href", function(){
         return  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + ycode;
              });  
             });
            });
        </script>
<a href="#" id="youtube" data-lity>
<button type="button" id="button">Jetzt anschauen!</button>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your new_link variable is created inside a function, so it is not reachable from outside of it's scope.

I would suggest using change event for the input field to assure href attribute of a button will be updated before it is clicked:

```
    <div>   
      <input type="text" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Video Code" id="code_input">
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="youtube" rel="prettyPhoto">
                Jetzt anschauen!    
            </a>   
        </div>
    </div>


$('#code_input').on('change', changeLink);

function changeLink() {
    var baselink="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=";
    var youtube_code = document.getElementById("code_input").value;
    var new_link = baselink.concat(youtube_code);
    $('#youtube').attr("href", new_link);
}
```

Also this way you don't need to use inline JavaScript to add an event listener.

Furthermore, nesting a button element inside a link is not valid HTML, so you should consider removing it.